# rqt_error_messages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, turtlebot3, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I have a problem to call the rqt. I followed the guide from e-Manual (Link:https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/basic_operation/#teleoperation) and would like to see the topic list from rqt. After I typed

### rqt

it showed following error messages:

" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/rqt", line 13, in 
sys.exit(main.main())

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 65, in main
hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 600, in main
plugin_manager.discover()

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_manager.py", line 125, in discover
self._plugin_menu.add_plugin(plugin_descriptor)

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_menu.py", line 82, in add_plugin
self._enrich_action(action, action_attributes, base_path)

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_menu.py", line 133, in _enrich_action
action_attributes['icon'], action_attributes.get('icontype', None), base_path)

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/icon_loader.py", line 46, in get_icon
raise UserWarning('icon "%s" not found' % str(path))

UserWarning: icon "/opt/ros/melodic/share/rqt_virtual_joy/resource/input-gaming.png" not found"

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391446/rqt_error_messages/) by [ENTMar](https://answers.ros.org/users/89860/entmar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To fix this error, need to install the missing package rqt_virtual_joystick:

https://github.com/aquahika/rqt_virtual_joystick

Suggested installation:

```
mkdir -p joystick_ws/src
cd joystick_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/aquahika/rqt_virtual_joystick
cd ..
catkin_make
echo 'source ~/joystick_ws/devel/setup.bash' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

To test: `rosrun rqt_virtual_joy rqt_virtual_joy`
Notice that the package is rqt_virtual_joy

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ENTMar](https://answers.ros.org/users/89860/entmar/) on 2021-11-23**:
Thank you very much :)
It works!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-23**:
Glad it works. If you could accept answer by clicking on check mark so the question can be considered closed.